# Cannot switch to root after applying Account Policies

Tags: terminal, bash, password, ssh

After running the following script, that applies some Account Policies I have lost the access to root account.
I took the script from [Git](https://gist.github.com/Freccia/37df869bd91a2c5edfffd4b02f5d24f0)

Executing command

```
sudo su -
```

Resulting in request of an old password and then a new password whatever I enter.

```
Last login: Thu Nov  2 17:59:43 on console
vitaly@IVRU ~ % sudo su -
Password:
Old Password:
New Password:
Retype New Password:
su: Sorry
vitaly@IVRU ~ % sudo su -
Old Password:
New Password:
Retype New Password:
su: Sorry
vitaly@IVRU ~ %
```

```
#!/bin/sh
 
###################################################################################
##   Create a pwpolicy XML file based upon variables and options included below.
##   Policy is applied and then file gets deleted.
##   Use "sudo pwpolicy -u <user> -getaccountpolicies"
##   to see it, and "sudo pwpolicy -u <user> -clearaccountpolicies" to clear it.
##
##    Tested on: OS X  10.10  10.11  10.12
####################################################################################
 
#########################################
# Make sure only root can run our script
#
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Please run this script as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
##########################################
 
#############################################################################
# Variables for script and commands generated below.
# EDIT AS NECESSARY FOR YOUR OWN PASSWORD POLICY
#
LOCKOUT=60                      # 1min lockout
# Sierra is sending more than one authentications attempts.
# There are reports that it will be fixed in 12.3.
#MAX_FAILED=10                   # 10 max failed logins before locking
PW_EXPIRE=180                   # 180 days password expiration
MIN_LENGTH=10                   # at least 10 chars for password
MIN_ALPHA_LOWER=1               # at least 1 lower case letter in password
MIN_UPPER_ALPHA=1               # at least 1 upper case letter in password
MIN_SPECIAL_CHAR=1              # at least one special character in password
PW_HISTORY=3                    # remember last 3 passwords
#
##############################################################################
 
###################################################
# create pwpolicy.plist in /private/var/tmp
# Password policy using variables above is:
# Change as necessary in variable flowerbox above
# -------------------------------------------------
 
echo "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>policyCategoryPasswordChange</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>policyContent</key>
<string>policyAttributeCurrentTime > policyAttributeLastPasswordChangeTime + (policyAttributeExpiresEveryNDays * 24 * 60 * 60)</string>
<key>policyIdentifier</key>
<string>Change every 180 days</string>
<key>policyParameters</key>
<dict>
<key>policyAttributeExpiresEveryNDays</key>
<integer>180</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
</array>
<key>policyCategoryPasswordContent</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>policyContent</key>
<string>policyAttributePassword matches '.{10,}+'</string>
<key>policyIdentifier</key>
<string>Has at least 10 characters</string>
<key>policyParameters</key>
<dict>
<key>minimumLength</key>
<integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>policyContent</key>
<string>policyAttributePassword matches '(.*[a-z].*){1,}+'</string>
<key>policyIdentifier</key>
<string>Has a lower case letter</string>
<key>policyParameters</key>
<dict>
<key>minimumAlphaCharactersLowerCase</key>
<integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>policyContent</key>
<string>policyAttributePassword matches '(.*[A-Z].*){1,}+'</string>
<key>policyIdentifier</key>
<string>Has an upper case letter</string>
<key>policyParameters</key>
<dict>
<key>minimumAlphaCharacters</key>
<integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>policyContent</key>
<string>policyAttributePassword matches '(.*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*){1,}+'</string>
<key>policyIdentifier</key>
<string>Has a special character</string>
<key>policyParameters</key>
<dict>
<key>minimumSymbols</key>
<integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>policyContent</key>
<string>none policyAttributePasswordHashes in policyAttributePasswordHistory</string>
<key>policyIdentifier</key>
<string>Does not match any of last 3 passwords</string>
<key>policyParameters</key>
<dict>
<key>policyAttributePasswordHistoryDepth</key>
<integer>3</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>" > /private/var/tmp/pwpolicy.plist
##### end of pwpolicy.plist generation script
###################################################
 
# clear account policy before loading a new one
pwpolicy -clearaccountpolicies
pwpolicy -setaccountpolicies /private/var/tmp/pwpolicy.plist
 
#delete staged pwpolicy.plist
rm -f /private/var/tmp/pwpolicy.plist
 
echo "Password policy successfully applied. Run \"sudo pwpolicy -getaccountpolicies\" to see it."
exit 0
```

Comment: Does `sudo -s` still work? And, of course, does the new password you are trying to set adhere to the rules you defined?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sudo -s works, but new session in not privileged session, the prompt is root@IVRU %, not #, and Yes I'd changed the password of my vitaly account to meet the policies before I applied them. And one more thing root account itself is not activated, may be this is the reason. Actually it is not clear which password it tries to change, mine (vitaly) or root.

Comment: Run `id` after `sudo -s`, I'm quite sure you are logged in as `root` then. The password you are asked to change is not the password of the `vitaly` account though.